# Cannot pass immutable value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer?' as inout argument

Tags: swift

```
var keyCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks
var valueCallbacks = kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks
  
var keys = [Unmanaged.passUnretained(kSecClass).toOpaque(), Unmanaged.passUnretained(kSecAttrApplicationTag).toOpaque(), Unmanaged.passUnretained(kSecAttrKeyType).toOpaque(), Unmanaged.passUnretained(kSecReturnRef).toOpaque()]
var values = [Unmanaged.passUnretained(kSecClassKey).toOpaque(), Unmanaged<AnyObject>.passUnretained(privateTag as AnyObject).toOpaque(), Unmanaged.passUnretained(kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA).toOpaque(), Unmanaged.passUnretained(kCFBooleanTrue).toOpaque()]

// let queryKey = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &keys, &values, 4, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks)//Error-- for "keys" this error show cannot pass immutable value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer?' as inout argument. 
let queryKey = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &keys, &values, 4, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks)
    
// Get the key.
var extractedItem: AnyObject?
let resultCode = SecItemCopyMatching(queryKey, &extractedItem)//cannot pass immutable value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer?' as inout argument
    
guard let keyItem = extractedItem, resultCode == noErr else {
        
return nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `CFDictionary` in Swift. It is not impossible, but not
worth the hassle. `CFDictionary` is toll-free bridged to `NSDictionary`
which in turn can be instantiated from a Swift `Dictionary`:

```
let query: NSDictionary = [
    kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
    kSecAttrApplicationTag: privateTag,
    kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
    kSecReturnRef: true
]
var extractedItem: AnyObject?
let resultCode = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &extractedItem)
```

Comment: but I get error for this line                                                                                     let attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, &keys, &values, 2, &keyCallbacks, &valueCallbacks) can you tell me how get this method

Comment: @OmBhagwan: There is no such line in my answer. – As I said, don't use CFDictionary.

Comment: yes @Martin I have checked after seen you answer but it is not work . Because CFDictionaryCreate is a method which give some attribute which attribute not in NSDictionary.

Comment: @OmBhagwan: How does it "not work"? My suggested code does exactly what you asked about in your question. If that does not help then please update and clarify your question.

Comment: @OmBhagwan: Any feedback?